# Rendering data from API array throws error

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Anytime I try to render data from an array that inside of the API object I get an error. It only happens on arrays.

Here is my error. But it is still rendering the data I want at this point.

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4061 Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at index.js:42.
at Nav (http://localhost:3000/main.92a9124351b8903c7446.hot-update.js:47:27)
at div
at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:60:80)
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:59561:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:59041:5)
```

The problem is, at this point it is actually rendering the data I want. But whenever I do another refresh, it throws this next error and completely breaks the code.

```
index.js:39 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
at Nav (index.js:39:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)`
```

Here is my code. I have highlighted the code throwing the error in the Nav.js file

In the App.js file is where im fetching the data

App.js

```
//Imports
import axios from 'axios'
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome' 
import { faFacebook, faInstagram, faTwitter} from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons' 



//Components
import Nav from "./Components/Nav"
import Footer from "./Components/Footer"

//Pages
import Home from "./Pages/Home"
import Inventory from "./Pages/Inventory"
import Contact from "./Pages/Contact"
import About from "./Pages/About"

// CSS
import "./App.css";

// Contexts
import UserContext from "./Contexts/UserContext"

function App() {

  const [weather, setWeather] = useState([])
  

  useEffect(() => {
   
    fetchWeather()
  }, [])

  const fetchWeather = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=32.779167&lon=-96.808891&appid=a91119eebbd33281141d01dd1405669b")
      setWeather(response.data)
      
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
 

  
  return (
    <div className="App">
     
      <Nav weather={weather} FontAwesomeIcon={FontAwesomeIcon} />
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
      <Route path='inventory' element={<Inventory />} />
      <Route path='about' element={<About />} />
      <Route path='contact' element={<Contact />} />
    </Routes>
       
      <Footer  FontAwesomeIcon={FontAwesomeIcon} faFacebook={faFacebook} faInstagram={faInstagram} faTwitter={faTwitter}/>
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my Nav.js file where I am rendering my API data

```
// import { useContext } from 'react'
import { faSun, faCloud, faCloudRain } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
// import UserContext from ".../.../contexts/UserContext"



import "./Nav.css"

const Nav = (weather, FontAwesomeIcon) => {
  console.log(weather)
   
  // const lightmode = useContext(UserContext)
  return (
    <nav
      className="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg navigation-clean navContainer"
      
    >
       <div className="container-fluid">
        <Link
          className="navbar-brand "
          to="/" 
        >
            
        Roc-City-Auto
        </Link>

      {/* WEATHER API */}
        <div>{weather.weather.name}</div>
        <div>{weather.weather.main?.temp}</div>
        

      {/* CONDITIONAL RENDERING FOR WEATHER API DISPLAY */}

                  {/* ========== STACKOVERFLOW QUESTION BELOW ========== */}
     
        {
        
          weather.weather.weather?.main === "Sun" ? <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSun} /> && <div>Its nice and sunny! Come on out to see us!</div> : null
        }
        {
          weather.weather.weather[0]?.main === "Clouds" ? <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCloud} /> && <div>It's a little cloudy, but rest assured, we are open and ready to help you!</div> : null
        }
        {
          weather.weather.weather?.main === "Rain" ? <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCloudRain} /> && <div>It's a little wet outside but we're open. Come on in!</div> : null
        }
        
                   {/* ========== STACK OVERFLOW QUESTION ABOVE ========== */}
            
            {/* MOBILE NAV BAR */}
        <button
          className="navbar-toggler"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navcol-1"
        >
          <span className="visually-hidden">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div id="navcol-1" className="collapse navbar-collapse show">
          <ul className="navbar-nav ms-auto">

            {/* HOME */}
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link
                className="nav-link active "
                to="/"
                
              >
                Home
              </Link>
            </li>

            {/* INVENTORY */}
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link
                className="nav-link "
                to="inventory"
                
              >
                Inventory
              </Link>
            </li>

            {/* CONTACT */}
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link
                className="nav-link "
                to="contact"
              
              >
                Contact Us
              </Link>
            </li>

            {/* ABOUT */}
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link
                className="nav-link "
                to="about"
                
              >
                About Us
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
            </div>
      </div> 
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

So far I've tried using optional chaining with no success. I also tried to set a separate state for the specific data I want and it still did not work. Leading me to believe its the way Im accessing the array with the data I want inside of it.

Comment: Can you share the full code, it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: yup just added it

Comment: Please add code in the post, people do not normally rewrite what you have in an image just to debug...please make it easy and share your text code in the post

Comment: Okay just updated it

Comment: Please read through [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) before your next update: if you get an error, show that error in your post (by copy-pasting it. No images, no "selectively summarizing it"), and then talk about which file and which line in that file it's triggered by, and what you already did in terms of debugging. In the absence of that: calling `setWeather(response.data)` without first verifying that the response is good is definitely a red flag. At the very least first verify that `response.data` exists, and actually contains the data that you expect it to.

Comment: It has been updated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. And, thank you for updating your question based on previous comments. May we please know the output printed from `console.log(weather)` (from `Nav.js` file) - need to see what exactly is the structure of `weather`. The reason for this request: it is observed that `weather.weather.weather?.main` is specified as well as `weather.weather.weather[0]?.main`. Is `weather.weather.weather` an object that has props `main` as well as `0`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly is wrong with your code, but I have found multiple issues that would help:

`App.js` file

- You are making a request that takes some time to come back with a response, so you need to check if there is no weather data, return loading state.

```
 if(!weather){
   return <div> Loading... </div>
 }
```

- you need to initialize the `useState` hook with `undefined` instead of empty array `[]` so we can check on the `weather` as stated in the previous point.

```
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState()
```

- you don't need to pass the `FontAwesomeIcon` library to the `<Nav/>` just import it there.

```
 <Nav weather={weather}/>
```

`Nav.js` file

- All component props are passed in the props object, so you need to destructure them here.

```
const Nav = ({ weather }) => {
```

- In consequence of destructuring the props, we need to change these values too

```
<div>{weather.name}</div>
<div>{weather.main?.temp}</div>
```

- use `<React.Fragment/>` as the `&&` operator will neglect the icon and will print only the `<div/>`

```
{
weather.weather[0].main === "Sun" ? <><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSun} /> <div>Its nice and sunny! Come on out to see us!</div></> : null
}
{
weather.weather[0]?.main === "Clouds" ? <React.Fragment><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCloud} /> <div>It's a little cloudy, but rest assured, we are open and ready to help you!</div></React.Fragment> : null
}
```

Related articles that I suggest reading:

- [React Conditonal Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)
- [React Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)
- [Passing props in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly what I needed.